# 3x images not rendering properly iPhone 6 plus

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6.1, iphone-6-plus

I have added @3x images to my project for two targets. when I deploy to device, I am able to notice one app renders correctly and the other is distorted. Both targets use same image. Because of this, images are shown very big and text is overlapping on other buttons. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know for sure it should work.  Ensure your @3x images are triple in dimensions.  I.e. if your original image is 100x100 pixels, the @3x should be 300x300 pixels.  I remember having it less than this and it caused the images to appear larger.

Comment: Image resolutions are correct. according to the guidelines. Considering your point, if image dimensions are not correct, then this problem should come for both the targets. In my case, the same image is rendered correctly in one target and in the other its not. :(